# Table Columns starts from right to left

Tags: html

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This HTML code gives me the following
1 2 3 4
5 6 7

But I want the table print the columns from right to left, as the following
4 3 2 1
*  7 6 5

*is space
I need it exactly like this result: http://postimg.org/image/la8aj8ckd/

Comment: tables are not very flexible. You can use `div`s or `<ul><li>` to achieve the same

Comment: What you actually want to do? HTML is not meant for dynamic display of information, It displays what you make it to display. The problem is easily solvable if you put extra `<td></td>` in second `<tr>` and reversing the order of your other `<td>` tag's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so by adding dir=rtl on the table like so:

```
<table border="1" DIR="RTL">
```

for more information, you can read http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html

Hope that helps

Comment: in my case error is: Unknown property: 'dir'css(unknownProperties)

Answer (score 2):

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wcCEf/).

Answer (score 0):

well its really kinda impossible without putting an extra `<td>` on the `<tr>` that lacks `<td>` because the lower `<tr>` follows the number of columns(`<td>`) of the tr before them.

`tables` are not that flexible, just think of a spreadsheet when using tables. you can use `<div>` in this rare cases.

**FYI**: `tables` are not intended for layouting, they are used only to display data properly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div